# Help prove this equality

Tags: calculus

I need help on proving this equality. Thanks
$$\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^t}{(i+1)^t}=-\frac{r}{r-(1+i)}$$ 
when $|r|<\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: You didn't provide us with a equation.

Comment: Equality? What equality?

Comment: Geometric series.

Comment: What is $i$ here?

Comment: i stands for discount rate

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange! A short tour will help you get acquainted with out community and get the most from  your experience. https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $|r| < \sqrt{2}$, therefore $\left|\frac{r}{1+i}\right|<1$

Therefore you have a geometric series with common ratio $\frac{r}{1+i}$ . The sum is 
$$\frac{r}{1+i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{r}{1+i}}=\frac{r}{1+i}\frac{1+i}{1+i-r}=\frac{r}{1+i-r}$$

Answer (score 0):

Infinite sum of a geometric series: 
\begin{align*}
S_{\infty} &= \frac{a}{1-r} \\ \\
&= \frac{\frac{r}{i+1}}{1-\frac{r}{i+1}} \\ \\
&= \frac{r}{(i+1)-r} \\ \\
&= -\frac{r}{r-(1+i)}
\end{align*}